# cannot read block number 3 from ledger, because Entry not found in index, skipping...?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I've created a network with 2 orgs each one with 2peers and 1ca
While instantiating the contract:

I get these errors and warnings for all peers:

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-01-31 18:04:41.664 UTC [gossip.state] handleStateRequest -> ERRO 071 cannot read block number 3 from ledger, because Entry not found in index, skipping...

peer0.org1.example.com|2020-01-31 18:04:47.103 UTC [gossip.state] requestBlocksInRange -> WARN 074 Wasn't able to process state response for blocks [3...3], due to Received state transfer response without payload
```

That's the script I used to setup the network and set the anchor peers

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com ca2.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com peer0.org2.example.com peer1.org1.example.com peer1.org2.example.com cli
docker ps -a

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx

# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
#anchor peer update
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli  peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/ca/ca.example.com-cert.pem -c mychannel -f /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/config/Org1MSPanchors.tx

#Fetch the channel block that was created and Join peer1.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec peer1.org1.example.com peer channel fetch oldest mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block


#Fetch the channel block that was created and Join peer0.org2.example.com to the channel.
docker exec peer0.org2.example.com peer channel fetch oldest mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8051" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer0.org2.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
#anchor peer update
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8051" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/" cli peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/ca/ca.example.com-cert.pem -c mychannel -f /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/config/Org2MSPanchors.tx

#Fetch the channel block that was created and Join peer1.org2.example.com to the channel.
docker exec peer1.org2.example.com peer channel fetch oldest mychannel.block -c mychannel --orderer orderer.example.com:7050
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" peer1.org2.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

That's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
#
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/244240018d5052a6010729319d92dcef5eeb3751f751fa6adb0fef9910bf6869_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  ca2.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca2.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/566407d6f5620125f9f9fa751fd93ad4795c773e3e4fdc59d1e339996f68c750_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca2.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 10051:10051
      - 10053:10053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 8051:8051
      - 8053:8053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 9051:9051
      - 9053:9053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/config/
        - /home/csd3458/Desktop/fabric-samples_v2/fabric-samples/first-network/scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts
        - /home/csd3458/Desktop/mychaincodes:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes
    networks:
        - basic
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    #depends_on:
    #  - orderer.example.com
    #  - peer0.org1.example.com
    #  - couchdb
```

and that's how I install and instantiate the contract

```
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel

#install the chaincode
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes/

export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:10051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes/

export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin\@org2.example.com/msp/
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:8051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"

peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes/

export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:9051
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes/

#instantiate the chaincode
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"

#invoke a transaction
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/ca/ca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:8051 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer1.org1.example.com:10051 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --peerAddresses peer1.org2.example.com:9051 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem  -c '{"Args":["createMyAsset","001","Model X"]}'
```

Whats the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s weird, could you please add the complete activities you have did? To understand the root cause

Comment: I've edited the question. Plz inform me if you need anything else